# Find the derivative with respect to $t$ of $y=2^{\left(t^2\right)}$

Tags: calculus

I got $\left(2^{t^2}\right)(\ln2)(2t)$ but I feel it isn't right, or should be simplified more or something. Can someone explain if this is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $y=2^{t^2}$. Set $t^2=g(t)$ and use chain rule. This gives us
$$y' = 2^{g(t)} \ln(2) g'(t) = 2\ln(2)t2^{t^2} = \ln(2) t 2^{t^2+1}$$

Comment: Can you explain where the + 1 came from in the exponent?

Comment: @user142342 There is a $2$ multiplying in-front, which one taken into the exponent adds $1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$y=2^{t^2}\\
\implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}\left(2^{t^2}\right)}{\mathrm{d}(t^2)}\dfrac{\mathrm{d}(t^2)}{\mathrm{d}t}=\left(2^{t^2}\ln 2\right)\left(2t\right)\\
\implies \dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}=2^{t^2}\times 2\times t\times \ln 2=2^{t^2+1}\times t\times \ln 2$$